# Python Spyder -- clear console

Tags: python, loops, console, screen

Trying to clear the console in Spyder within a loop. Basically asking for input data and then re-setting screen after loop is finished for new inputs (cleaning everything in console from previous input).

Ok, I want to clear the console within a program (loop): Ask for "Data Set 1" => clean screen => "Ask for Data Set 2" => clean screen etc.

For this, I tested various offered answers in the internet, amongst others below:

`import os os.system('cls')`

The console gets cleared, but with a delay. Basically, the clearing occurs AFTER the loop is exited even though the command is called at the start of the loop (or the end, or somewhere in between ... tried everything).

To check that not the loop is the issue, I tried below simple version (just copy - paste from one of the internet solutions):

`import os  k = input("Enter your name: ")  os.system('cls')     #Screen SHOULD get cleared here  l = input('Hi ')     #Screen gets cleaned AFTER this input is provided`

I tested as alternative:

`from IPython import get_ipython

k = input("Enter your name: ")
get_ipython().magic('clear')     #Screen gets cleaned
l = input('Hi ')     `

This kind of works for this simple example, but in my loop, it moves all the text before the next input request off-screen (it is there, but I have to scroll up in the console to see it)

I am a beginner, so I am a bit biting the keyboard right now ... any idea why this happens would be welcome. I just want to have exactly the same result from my code as if I write 'cls' straight into the console.

Running Spyder through Anaconda with following system version / info:

- Spyder version: 5.4.3  (conda)
- Python version: 3.11.4 64-bit
- Qt version: 5.15.2
- PyQt5 version: 5.15.7
- Operating System: Windows 10